Eastern redbud hack job
I am so sad. We had some yardwork done today. We were anticipating having our yard cleaned up, we were not anticipating having our trees hacked up. Our eastern redbud was beautiful and dropped to the ground and they essentially gave it a bowl cut. We're in the middle of summer and the middle of a heat wave. How can I ensure our tree doesn't die. I also need reassurance. Will our trees bad haircut grow out? This tree was what made me fall in love with our house when we were house hunting with it's beautiful blossoms. I'm devastated.

pictures please!

If they left at least 2/3rds of the tree it's unlikely to die from the pruning. Try for better communication with the next yard work people you hire. "clean up" is terribly vague, especially if the person with a saw or loppers sees "overgrown tree drooping to the ground" and likes lollipop trees from children's book illustrations...

Without seeing the tree, I would recommend that you contact a CERTIFIED arborist and have them prune it so that the new growth doesn't compromise the health of the tree. This will probably involve a fairly severe pruning, possibly over several visits. A topped tree is an eventually unhealthy tree.

Knowing what you want is an essential part of getting what you want. Pruning can produce tall out-of-the-way-s, wide shade-for-15-people-s, strong fruit-givers, strong shade-to-the-house-s. A second point: middle of the summer is the worst time to prune.
